# HDMI screen does not adjust to the resolution

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, display, display-resolution, overscan

You see I have a problem with the system resolutions.

I count a screen connected by VGA and a TV connected by HDMI.
With the screen in VGA I have no problems.

But with the television connected by HDMI the desktop leaves the screen, so it is not possible to visualize it completely.
I have tried to put the screens in mirror mode, separately and nothing.

I have not managed to adjust the desktop resolution to this screen.
I have an Nvidia GT 730 card.

I have installed the drivers, I have been urging to add an additional resolution to HDMI of 1280x1024.

---

TV HDMI image

[image]

---

VGA Monitor:

[image]

---

```
darkcrizt @ PC-Desktop  ~
└─ $ ▶ xrandr --output HDMI-0 --set underscan on
X Error of failed request:  BadName (named color or font does not exist)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  11 (RRQueryOutputProperty)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  33
Try adjusting the overscan but without success.


darkcrizt @ PC-Desktop  ~
└─ $ ▶ xrandr

Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1280 x 1024, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VGA-0 connected primary 1280x1024+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 380mm x 300mm
   1280x1024     60.02*+
   1280x960      60.00  
   1024x768      60.00  
   800x600       60.32  
   640x480       59.94  
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1280x720+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 708mm x 398mm
   1280x720      60.00*+  59.94  
   1920x1080     60.05    60.00  
   1440x480      60.05  
   720x480       59.94    60.05  
   640x480       59.93  


darkcrizt @ PC-Desktop  ~
└─ $ ▶ gtf 1280 1024 60
  # 1280x1024 @ 60.00 Hz (GTF) hsync: 63.60 kHz; pclk: 108.88 MHz
  Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  108.88  1280 1360 1496 1712  1024 1025 1028 1060  -HSync +Vsync
```

In windows 10 without problems I get this and even in a Raspberry Pi you can see on the TV a full desktop and adjusted to the screen.
But in Ubuntu it is not possible.

Someone who can advise me with what I have to do.
Good day and I thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The monitor and TV have different vertical resolutions, so if you have both of them show the same picture, one of them will show more than the other.

XRandR requires that the framebuffer size is at least large enough so that all output views fit into it, so the larger of the two wins if you use both of them with their preferred video mode. Since they have no common video modes (one is 4:3 and the other 16:9, and neither has any scaled modes), your options are somewhat limited:

- set the monitor to panning mode, with `--output VGA-0 --panning 1280x1024` which will probably be annoying to use, but would allow you to reach the entire screen with the mouse at least
- set up two separate viewports, using `--left-of`, `--right-of`, `--above` or `--below`. Since the horizontal resolution is the same, stacking them vertically would not create invisible areas (but window managers are usually smart enough to not move anything into an area not displayed on any monitor).